# nginx codeigniter rewrite: Controller name conflicts with directory

Tags: php, codeigniter, url-rewriting, nginx

I'm trying out nginx and porting my existing apache configuration to nginx. I have managed to reroute the codeigniter url's successfully, but I'm having a problem with one particular controller whose name coincides with a directory in site root.

I managed to make my codeigniter url's work as it did in Apache except that, I have a particular url say `http://localhost/hello` which coincides with a **`hello`** directory in site root. Apache had no problem with this. But nginx routes to this directory instead of the controller.

**My reroute structure** is as follows

```
http://host_name/incoming_url => http://host_name/index.php/incoming_url
```

All the codeigniter files are in site root.

My nginx configuration (relevant parts)

```
server {

listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
#listen   [::]:80 default ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6

root /path/to/site/root;
index index.php index.html index.htm;

# Make site accessible from http://localhost/
server_name localhost;

location / {
    # First attempt to serve request as file, then
    # as directory, then fall back to index.html

    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php/$request_uri;

    #apache rewrite rule conversion

    if (!-e $request_filename){
        rewrite ^(.*)/?$ /index.php?/$1 last;
    }

    # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
    # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
}

location ~ \.php.*$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini

    # With php5-cgi alone:
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    # With php5-fpm:
    #fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

I'm new to nginx and I need help in figuring out this directory conflict with the Controller name. I figured this configuration from various sources in the web, and any better way of writing my configuration is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you are telling nginx to check for the existence of the folder before passing it to the main controller

```
try_files $uri ($uri/) /index.php/$request_uri;
                 |
             this part
```

You can simply fix it by telling nginx not to look for the folders, just by removing that part

```
try_files $uri /index.php/$request_uri;
```

**PS**: `$request_uri` already contains a leading `/`

[check the wiki link](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#.24request_uri)

So the more correct way is to do

```
try_files $uri /index.php$request_uri;
```

**PS #2**

```
#apache rewrite rule conversion

if (!-e $request_filename){
    rewrite ^(.*)/?$ /index.php?/$1 last;
}
```

This part should be removed, the `try_files` statement already handles this part and does exactly the same.

I also believe that your site will still work after removing this line too

```
fastcgi_index index.php;
```

and this

```
fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
```

I never really use these.

And your config is missing a `root`, I think this is why you needed those lines.

**EDIT:**

As you mentioned the website doesn't work if the rewrite is removed, I noticed there's a slight difference between the `try_files` and the `rewrite` statement, we need to fix the `try_files` to do the same thing that the `rewrite` does, so it will changed from this

```
try_files $uri /index.php$request_uri;
```

To this

```
try_files $uri /index.php/?$request_uri;
```

After that the rewrite should be ok to remove.

Comment: hi. thanks for replying. but i tried all the above suggestions and removing `$url/` part does not work at all. gives me a access denied. Also I have a `root` in the server directive. Is it needed in the location directive too ?. And removing the if block `if(!-e $request_filename) ..` also leads to `access denied message` I'm new to nginx and the config is mostly taken from various sources. Please point me in the right direction.

Comment: no. just a single access denied line in the entire page. Removing `fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;` as you suggested works and had no effect in the config file. But removing the `if (!-e $request_filename){
    rewrite ^(.*)/?$ /index.php?/$1 last;
}` part makes things go haywire.

Comment: ok I think I know why, i just noticed something, I'll edit my answer

Comment: hi. i tried the edited `try_files` and removed the `if block`, but still gives me an access denied and no codeigniter url works. Having the `if block` and the edited `try files` results in the old behaviour - downloads the conflicting directory(actually chrome downloads, firefox gives 403 for the directory)when that particular controller is called.

Comment: I understand the 403, it's expected, because you're trying to list a folder without allowing folder listing, the access denied is strange though, are you sure file permissions are fine? check the nginx log too to understand why exactly it's denied

Comment: another thought, I haven't really used code igniter much before, but could be the `access denied` message a response from the code igniter frame work it self?

Comment: hi. the access denied is from nginx similar from this [link](http://ffct.cc/solving-nginx-php-fpm-access-denied-issue/). And the error log says "Direcory access index of /path/to/folder/ is forbidden". I could rename/remove the directory, but still curious on why nginx has this problem and not apache.

Comment: without the `$uri/` this shouldn't happen, do you reload the settings every time before you test?